# How to conditionally modify cell in column X based upon value in column Y

Tags: python, pandas

I'm modifying a csv file using Python Pandas. I am fairly new to this and am experimenting Pandas as an alternative for Excel regarding data handling and manipulation.

Now I run into a problem trying to conditionally change the value of a cell in column `df.duration` based upon the value of a cell on the same row in column `df.paymenttype`.

So I've tried modifying the value in `df.duration` using the .loc method.

```
df.loc[df.paymenttype == 'cash', df.duration] = (df.duration % 1)
```

It gives the expected outcome and works fine. However, in this case the outcome of `df.duration % 1` returns an unwanted value 0.0 for certain rows.  It is mathematically correct but in case `df.duration % 1` returns 0.0 I want to set the value of `df.duration` to 1.

So I thought I might be able to do something like this:

```
df.loc[df.paymenttype == 'cash', df.duration] = 1 if df.duration % 1 == 0 else (df.duration % 1)
```

This however returns: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

Now I am wondering two things:

1. Why is this ValueError raised and how could I fix this?

I could and should be doing more research on this myself before dropping this question here and I will. But more importantly and for future projects (since I am fairly new to Python and Pandas):

2. I am now wondering whether the `.loc` method is the right way to conditionally change the values for column cells in general and in this certain case where I want to add a conditional statement when setting the value.

Comment: To your first question, `df.duration` is a Series. How would you, for example, interpret `if [0, 1, 2] == 1`? `loc` is a reasonable way forward, but the right hand side of the expression isn't necessarily keeping up with the row-wise operation on the left.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your initial broadcast using `.loc`; it worked perfectly. However if the conditions start getting more complex, you might want to take a look at [`pd.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) or [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

Also see [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column).

As for your problem at hand: why not use `df['duration'].replace(0.0, 1)`?

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. Not just an answer on the problem at hand but also some guidance on how to go forward manipulating data using Pandas. Now not sure whether it is a duplicate question to _Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column_

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use dataframe `.apply` method. In your case:

```
def my_func(x):
    if x%1 == 0:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return x%1

df['duration'][df['paymenttype']=='cash'] = df['duration'][df['paymenttype']=='cash'].apply(my_func)
```

And one more suggestion is to use `df['column_name']` instead of `df.column_name`. Because sometimes there could be a space in column name.

Good luck with learning Pandas!